# Errno set by socket() is undocumented in the manpage

Tags: c, linux, sockets, manpage

The manpage of [`socket(3p)`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/socket.3p) documents the signature to this function and a basic introduction on how to use it. The [error section](https://man.archlinux.org/man/socket.3p#ERRORS) of this document lists a few `errno` values with explanations on why the error occurs. Unfortunately, I got an undocumented error reading `EPERM` with the numerical number `1` indicating `Operation not permitted`. The undocumented `errno` was initially discovered under the ArchLinux environment with `glibc-2.33` and `clang-12.0.1`. I hope the following proof-of-concept(PoC) could be reproduced in other Linux environments:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

int main() {
    socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
    return errno;
}
```

The following command may help reproduce, where the PoC code stores in file `raw-socket-poc.c`:

```
$ clang -O0 -g raw-socket-poc.c -o raw-socket-poc
$ ./raw-socket-poc; errno $?
EPERM 1 Operation not permitted
```

Additional observations show that changing `IPPROTO_TCP` to `IPPROTO_UDP` helps nothing. However, by replacing `IPROTO_TCP` to the suggested `0`, the program ends up with a documented error `EPROTONOSUPPORT 93 Protocol not supported`. Further experiments noticed that running the original PoC as root yold no error. Unfortunately, the undocumented error occurred if the PoC ran as an unprivileged user with the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability. The capability promotion for the PoC associated with `# setcap CAP_NET_RAW=+eip ./raw-socket-poc` and a double-checked with `$ getcap ./raw-socket-poc` where `./raw-socket-poc cap_net_raw=eip` showed.

With limited information, conclusions are hard to make on whether the lack of documentation is intended or a by-design product. So we may appreciate it if there are explanations on how things work with manpage and raw socket-related capabilities.

Comment: `PROLOG This manual page is part of the POSIX Programmer's Manual. The Linux implementation of this interface may differ...` Please in the spirit of this forum, please state a question in your post. Why are you writing here?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for the information. However, the Further Directions sections is empty and See Also section does not contain Linux version of the socket manpage

Comment: @KamilCuk I noticed that there is a `socket(7)`, which overviews the socket interface on Linux. However, I cannot find the corresponding error section in this document.

Comment: There is a distinction between man sections. `3p` is from POSIX, POSIX is a standardization, specification, not documentation, it's basically copied here https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html . The section `7` is for some miscellaneous stuff, seems like `socket(2)` has documentation of `socket` system call. POSIX has some "standardized" format for all system calls documentation, so there are these sections everywhere, and they are sometimes empty.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It's glad to know where the words come from. It's worth a read.

Comment: @dbush mentioned that this cannot be reproduced in CentOS7. So I highly suspect the kernel patched by Arch is to blame. I will close this question and move to Arch community's BBS for further work on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [`man 2 socket`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html), at the bottom of the "ERRORS" section. you'll see that it mentions that other errors can be generated.

```
ERRORS
       EACCES Permission to create a socket of the specified type and/or  pro‐
              tocol is denied.

       EAFNOSUPPORT
              The  implementation  does not support the specified address fam‐
              ily.

       EINVAL Unknown protocol, or protocol family not available.

       EINVAL Invalid flags in type.

       EMFILE Process file table overflow.

       ENFILE The system limit on the total number  of  open  files  has  been
              reached.

       ENOBUFS or ENOMEM
              Insufficient  memory is available.  The socket cannot be created
              until sufficient resources are freed.

       EPROTONOSUPPORT
              The protocol type or the specified  protocol  is  not  supported
              within this domain.

       Other errors may be generated by the underlying protocol modules.
```

If we then check [`man 7 raw`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html):

```
SYNOPSIS

       #include <sys/socket.h>
       #include <netinet/in.h>
       raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, int protocol);

...

ERRORS

       EACCES User tried to send to a broadcast address without having
              the broadcast flag set on the socket.

       EFAULT An invalid memory address was supplied.

       EINVAL Invalid argument.

       EMSGSIZE
              Packet too big.  Either Path MTU Discovery is enabled (the
              IP_MTU_DISCOVER socket flag) or the packet size exceeds
              the maximum allowed IPv4 packet size of 64 kB.

       EOPNOTSUPP
              Invalid flag has been passed to a socket call (like
              MSG_OOB).

       EPERM  The user doesn't have permission to open raw sockets.
              Only processes with an effective user ID of 0 or the
              CAP_NET_RAW attribute may do that.

       EPROTO An ICMP error has arrived reporting a parameter problem.
```

We see that `EPERM` can be generated.

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, according to this page, the PoC with `CAP_NET_RAW` should not yield this error again, which contradicts to the observation.

Comment: @TJM Works for me on CentOS7 when using `setcap`.  Could be a difference in how Arch works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm glad to hear that this works on other distros. I personally believe this might relate to the patches modified kernel whom Arch employs. Anyways, I will ask this in Arch community and accept your answer.